# SSRS One report connecting to Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services

I need to get data (IDs) from Oracle.
Then I need to look up these IDs in SQL Server and output rows.
Can this be done in SSRS? Please suggest solution, if possible.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-multi-value-parameter-to-a-report?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can have more then one datasource on an SSRS report.
This will show you how to connect to Oracle using a datasource in SSRS. https://www.oracle.com/a/otn/docs/database/connecting-ssrs-to-oracle-adb.pdf
Query the (ID) you need from Oracle - store in a variable and then use it to get the needed data from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataset with a query for the IDs from Oracle as use it as the source for a multi-value Parameter (@ID).

[image]

Then use the @ID parameter in your query from SQL Server.

The report will get the IDs from Oracle, put them in the @ID parameter. Then your query from SQL would filter for the IDs in the @ID parameter in the SSRS report.